# Не срабатывает Visual Studio Code debugger. Ошибка “$ is not defined” в консоли VSCode (в chrome dev tools чисто)

Tags: javascript, отладка, visual-studio-code

**Изучают отладчик VSCode. Не срабатывают точки останова в jQuery коде.** 
VSCode выдает ошибку

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\Desktop\test_VSCode\VSCode_learn\js\script.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

**Сам код скрипта jQuery работает корректно. 

В отладчике Chrome DevTools чисто, ошибок нет ни в консоли, ни в Network.

Файлы подключены в index.html**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Точки останова не для jquery работают корректно. 
Например на этом скрине первая не срабатывает, вторая работает корректно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы отладчик VSCode корректно работал с jquery кодом?

Comment: посмотри плагины для дебага jq из коробки js дебажится нодой, а та конечно не знает что такое jq

Comment: Точно! Спасибо.